# Flutter convert string in list double

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a response from REST API that return this:

`var time = [{"duration":"00m 25s"},{"duration":"12m 08s"},{"duration":"02m 09s"},{"duration":"01m 25s"}, {"duration":"02m 05s"}]`

I want to transform this list in:

`var newTime = [0.25, 12.08, 2.09, 1.25, 2.05]`

Comment: it should be 12.08, 2.09 and 2.05?

Comment: yes! sorry... now I correct

Comment: correct last 2.5 as 2.05

Comment: .....just made!

Comment: Please share what you've tried.

Comment: Uh, those doubles are neither minutes nor seconds nor really anything mathematically useful.  Are you sure you want useless-for-computation values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

```dart
 var time = [{"duration":"00m 25s"},{"duration":"12m 08s"},{"duration":"02m 09s"},{"duration":"01m 25s"}, {"duration":"02m 05s"}];
  
  var newList = time.map((time) {
    String clippedMinutes; // will get the minutes part
    String clippedSeconds; //// will get the seconds part
    String fullTime = time['duration']; // full time part from each Map
    final splittedTimeList = fullTime.split(' '); // splits the full time
    clippedMinutes = splittedTimeList[0];
    clippedSeconds = splittedTimeList[1];
    return double.parse('${clippedMinutes.substring(0, clippedMinutes.length - 1)}.${clippedSeconds.substring(0, clippedSeconds.length - 1)}');
  }).toList();
  
  print(newList); // output: [0.25, 12.08, 2.09, 1.25, 2.05]
```

If it helped you don't forget to upvote

Comment: this answer is similar to mine, I answered it earlier. :)

Comment: @TirthPatel i made it in dartpad at the same time, and to be honest, neither of our answers are the best aproach for this.
That last answer from the dude that i cant pronounce his name using RegEx is the best approach for it.

Comment: and btw, i upvoted your answer when i found you used the same approach @TirthPatel

Answer (score 3):

You can do string manipulation using splitting string using some delimiter like space and applying transformation via `map`.

```dart
void main() {
  var time = [
    {"duration": "00m 25s"},
    {"duration": "12m 08s"},
    {"duration": "02m 09s"},
    {"duration": "01m 25s"},
    {"duration": "02m 05s"}
  ];
  time.map((e) {
    final val = e['duration'].split(' '); // split by space

    final result = val[0].substring(0, val[0].length - 1) + '.' +
        val[1].substring(0, val[1].length - 1); // concat number by removing unit suffix

    return double.tryParse(result); // parsing to double.
  }).forEach((e) => print(e)); // 0.25, 12.08, 2.09, 1.25, 2.05
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My contribution:

```
main(List<String> args) {
  final times = [{"duration":"00m 25s"},{"duration":"12m 08s"},{"duration":"02m 09s"},{"duration":"01m 25s"}, {"duration":"02m 05s"}];
  var regExp = RegExp(r'(\d\d)m (\d\d)s');
  var newData = times.map((e) => double.parse(e['duration'].replaceAllMapped(regExp, (m) => '${m[1]}.${m[2]}')));

  print(newData);
}
```

Result:

```
(0.25, 12.08, 2.09, 1.25, 2.05)
```